# How to pass parameters to Windows XP batch file from a text file?

Tags: redirect, parameters, input, batch-file, dos

I want to find where is a certain java class from from hundreds jar files. I want to use batch file to do it:

First i get a list of all jar files:

```
dir /s *.jar > jarfiles.txt
```

Then create a bacth file findclass.bat:

```
jar tf %1
```

finally i run this batch like this:

```
findclass < jarfiles.txt
```

But this does not work.

What's wrong and what should I do?

Or any other better way to locate  a class than using batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see `HELP FOR`

and then try

`FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (jarfiles.txt) DO findclass %%A`

or just

`FOR /R %%A IN (*.jar) DO findclass %%A`

Comment: If `findclass` is a second batch file, you will want to `CALL findclass` so it will return control to the first batch file. Alternatively, if findclass.bat is just a one-liner, you could forgo the second batch file and just run the line directly.

Comment: right! the line would then be `FOR /R %%A IN (*.jar) DO jar tf %%A`

Comment: @wang.chance: Just for clarification: this last piece of advice from *PA* means just one batch file to do *all* the job. No `jarfiles.txt` and no `findclass.bat`. A perfect substitution, to my mind.

Comment: It works perfect! But to run it from DOS shell directly (without batch file), double percent sign does not work. Should be single percent sign: `FOR /R %A IN (*.jar) DO jar tf %A`

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, just replace `<your class name>` with your class name

```
@echo off
set JARTEXTFILE=jarfiles.txt

dir /S /B *.txt > %JARTEXTFILE%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %JARTEXTFILE%"') do (
    jar tf %%A | findstr /C:"<your class name>"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use my ClassFinder utility. It's simple, fast and built for the purpose!

http://www.adarshr.com/papers/classfinder

```
Usage:

   java  -jar  cf.jar  SEARCH  [DIRECTORY]  [OPTIONS]...

Searches all JAR files in the current directory and its sub-directories for
entries matching the SEARCH argument. If DIRECTORY is provided, searching will
be done in that location instead of the current directory.

SEARCH:

  A search string containing the class name (entry name). Wild card (*) is
  supported. Package separator can be either of `/', `\' or `.'.

  Examples:

    java.lang.String
    java/util/ArrayList
    java/lang/Str*B*er

  If non ".class" entries also need to be searched, option -a (--all-types)
  should be specified. Please see the OPTIONS section for a more detailed
  explanation.

DIRECTORY:

  If this is not provided, current directory and all its sub-directories will
  be used for performing the search. However, if this argument is provided,
  the same and its sub-directories will be used as the location to fetch JAR
  files from.

  If a recursive scan is not needed, option -s (--shallow) can be specified.

OPTIONS:

  -h          --help
                   Shows this help
  -o [path]   --redirect-output
                   Redirect output to a file path supplied.
  -x [x1,x2]  --archive-extensions
                   Extensions in addition to the default ".jar". Comma or space
                   separated list accepted.
  -i          --insensitive-case
                   Case insensitive search.
  -q          --quiet
                   Silent search without the progress bar animation.
  -a          --all-types
                   Removes the filtering on ".class" types so that other types
                   such as ".properties", ".xml", etc can also be searched for.
  -s          --shallow
                   Performs a shallow search. Doesn't recurse.

Examples:

   java  -jar  cf.jar  org/apache/log4j/Level  D:\Frameworks
   java  -jar  cf.jar  *OracleDriver  C:\oracle -x jar,zip
   java  -jar  cf.jar  messages.properties  D:\IBM\WebSphere -a -x jar,war,ear
   java  -jar  cf.jar  util.*  D:\Java -i -q
```